# DirectoryChooserConfig does not show big SD card

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

I have troubles with showing 120GB sd card on Samsung S7 edge using DirectoryChooserConfig.Builder in my app. It works great on this device with smaller sd cards, works great on other devices with smaller sd cards. What can be the reason for these? This is android 6, by the way.

this is net.rdei.android.dirchooser

Comment: There is nothing in the Android SDK named `DirectoryChooserConfig`. If you are using a third-party library with this class, contact the authors of that library, as we do not know what the library is.

Comment: this is net.rdei.android.dirchooser. Sorry, forgot to mention

Comment: Cant you provide a decent link?

Comment: @greenapps https://github.com/passy/Android-DirectoryChooser